# Why it takes days, weeks and months to setup a CI system for the project already in progress

Tags: continuous-integration

I am new to CI system. I am not asking any technical or programming question. I read in a book mentioning that

1) For a project that is already in progress, to set up a CI system it takes days, weeks and months.

2) For a project which is new , to set up a CI system it takes only few hours.

I found these two statements very interesing but lack of proper explaination and no justification. Does anyone know a proper answer why it takes much time to set up a CI system on a progressed project rather than on a new project.

Proper answers will be appreciated.

Regards,

Krishna.

Comment: OT here - try http://programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just think about it for a minute and the answer is obvious.

If you have no architecture and zero lines of code, CI starts as an academic exercise.

If you have 80k lines of code running across multiple servers and databases, there is a huge amount of work required to both identify the control points and checks necessary, build the tools and processes required to continually test, and then implement them in a way that will not pose any risk to the live system.

It's not strictly true to say that there are only a few hours involved, since CI planning and implementation will be distributed throughout the life of a project, however, it is certainly much easier to build CI in from the start than it is to retrospectively implement it.